# Classifying a Raphael paper into 20x20 divisions

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a paper with 400 x 500 in size. I am trying to divide this into 20 x 20 pixels with below code

```
var dpH = 500, dpW = 400, drawPad = new Raphael(document.getElementById('p'),
        dpW, dpH);
for ( var i = 0; i <= dpH / 20; i++) {
    drawPad.path("M" + 1 + " " + ((i * 20) + 1) + "L" + dpW + " "
            + ((i * 20) + 1));
}
for ( var j = 0; j <= (dpW / 20); j++) {
    drawPad.path("M" + ((j * 20) + 1) + " " + 1 + "L" + ((j * 20) + 1) + " "
            + dpH);
}
```

And HTML markup is like below

```
<div id="p" style="background-image:url(image.png)"> </div>
```

with same height and width of Background Image.

My original requirement was making the image.png as Rapheal paper. But I was failed to do that. So I made it as background-image to the DIV#P. Then converted the DIv to Paper.
Here are my questions related to above

1. Does all the pixels of Background-Image and DIV match with each other?
2. The way I did above is to classify the total paper into 20x20 pixel divisions. Is that correct way of doing?
3. What is the width of the drawn line?

Please help me on this.

Comment: If you're looking for an example on how to load an image into a rapheal paper check this --> http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/71017bb984d44c55/886897c33b6e04c3

Comment: @lkptrzk Embedding an image into Raphael paper has some severe issues in IE

Comment: I'm at work on XP/IE8 and the fiddle in that thread worked for me

Comment: Yes it works.. When you embed an image, the image will be embedded with zoom. Please check it in ie9. I have posted the same question recently

Comment: @SoI I dont't undestand what are you trying to accomplish with the 20x20 grid, If you tell us why do you need it (or how are you trying to us it) we might be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand you correctly; What you really want is to get the raw image data for 20x20 squares of the image.

Here's how you can extract image data with Canvas ([also on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzrN9/3/)):

```js
var dpH = 500,
    dpW = 400,
    ctx = document.getElementById('p').getContext('2d'),
    exportData = function() {
        var data;
        for (var y=0, yl=dpH/20; y<yl; y++) {
            for (var x=0, xl=dpW/20; x<xl; x++) {
                imgData = ctx.getImageData(x*20, y*20, 20, 20).data;
                console.log("Image data for " + x*20 + ", " + y*20, imgData);
                // data is an array with 4 values pr pixel
                // Top left pixel in the 20x20 square
                r = imgData[0]; // red
                g = imgData[1]; // green
                b = imgData[2]; // blue
                a = imgData[3]; // alpha
                console.log("RGBa of " + x*20 + ", " + y*20 + ": ", r, g, b, a);
            }
        }
    },
    drawImage = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        exportData(this);
    };

var img = new Image();
img.onload = drawImage;
img.src = "image.png"; // has to be on the same domain
```

---

** Original answer **

1. The result is a DIV with an SVG-element inside, and a background image behind it. The browser ([if it supports SVG](http://caniuse.com/svg)) will render them on top of each other. Do you want to extract pixel values? If so, you have to do this through HTML5 Canvas instead of SVG.
2. Sorry, I don't understand. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want the pixel data for 20x20 squares? With Raphael you are just drawing lines on top of the picture.
3. The defaut with of a path is 1 pixels. You can change this by setting an [attribute](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr) on the path. Example ([also on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/LzrN9/)):

```js
var dpH = 500,
    dpW = 400,
    drawPad = Raphael(document.getElementById('p'), dpW, dpH),
    style = {
        "stroke"       : "#fff", // white
        "stroke-width" : 2 // default 1
    };

for ( var i = 0; i <= dpH / 20; i++) {
    drawPad.path("M" + 1 + " " + ((i * 20) + 1) + "L" + dpW + " "
            + ((i * 20) + 1)).attr(style);
}
for ( var j = 0; j <= (dpW / 20); j++) {
    drawPad.path("M" + ((j * 20) + 1) + " " + 1 + "L" + ((j * 20) + 1) + " "
            + dpH).attr(style);
}​
```

Comment: Really the one who updated this question removed my actual questions. I have seen only the code not text.. I am sorry for this..

Comment: Is there any function available to convert the paper into a grid with pixels?

Comment: You can't get pixel data from an SVG, but you can with Canvas. Can you say a bit more about what you're trying to do? It's difficult to guess based on the little info you've given.